# How do I divide two numbers?

Tags: commerce, 9

I seem to be doing something wrong. I am trying to divide the price by 1.2 in commerce-invoice.html.twig.

With `{{ invoice_item.getTotalPrice|commerce_price_format / 1.2}}`,
when `invoice_item.getTotalPrice|commerce_price_format` is 10, I get 8.33; when `invoice_item.getTotalPrice|commerce_price_format` is 10.5, I get 8.33 instead of 8.75.

Comment: This is a question related to Twig. Maybe you need to use `//` instead of `/` see https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#math

Comment: Looks like a caching issue. 

Comment: "Maybe you need to use // instead of /" This returns the floored integer result. I need the returned value will be a floating point number. But it calculates it wrong.  {{ invoice_item.getTotalPrice|commerce_price_format }} takes it as an integer

Comment: hm ok... was just a try :) are you sure that the variables had the values you described above? Or maybe you shouldn't use commerce_price_format before calculating.. I don't know what this function does but I think you should calculate without formatting

Comment: Preprocess this. Twig is not a good place to do this.

Answer (score -3):

without commerce_price_format any number divisible by 1.2 = 0.83333333333333
divide by 1.5 is = 0.66666666666667

On division takes {{ invoice_item.getTotalPrice }} = 1